# Twig don't render HTML tags in the label form tag

Tags: symfony, twig, symfony-forms

When I use this code :

```
{{ form_widget(form.submit, {'attr': {'class': 'send'}, 'label': '<span id="sendArrow"><i class="fa fa-arrow-right fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>'}) }}
```

*Expected output*

[image: this]

*Actual output*

[image: output]

I tried to use the raw filter, to clear the cache, to add the label tag in the PHP file... But I have the same result! And when I use the Firefox Developer Tool, I have [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VRsTZ.png): Firefox recognize the node as text...

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that the (re)escaping – of even the `raw` content – is being done in the "label" part of the twig rendering process.

Why not render the label outside the form widget call?

(Preserve the click-to-focus behaviour of labels by adding a `for` attr on the label corresponding the widget.)

```
<label for="{{ form.vars.submit.id }}"><span id="sendArrow"><i class="fa fa-arrow-right fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i></span></label>

{{ form_widget(form.submit, {'attr': {'class': 'send'}}) }}
```